# Create a folder in slave node using Jenkins pipeline groovy script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, git, permissions

I have a Jenkins job which runs on a slave node on another machine, both master and slave run on windows. The slave node is being run as a windows service. The main repository has git submodule included. After checking-out the code for both the main and sub module repositories, I need to create a folder inside of the submodule folder and write a file into it with some basic deployment details like tag, version, etc. Structure is something like this:

***`main -> submodule -> {newfolder} -> {newfile}`***

I am using the mkdir() to create the folder, but it is not being created. I have also tried the dir() method. But nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help on this:

1. Do I need to provide elevated permissions set for the windows service used to trigger the slave node?
2. Do I need to provide permissions at folder level?

Any other check that I am missing, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved with the use of [File Operations Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/) methods like `folderCreateOperation` & `fileCreateOperation`. Example code snippet below:

```
def path = "${workspace}\submodule\newFolder"
fileOperations([folderCreateOperation(folderPath: path)])
dir(path) {
    fileOperations([fileCreateOperation(fileName: 'newFile.properties', fileContent: 'Git_Tag=${env.Git_Tag}')])
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).